# Google play services error DEBUG: Application is pausing, which disconnects the RTMP client

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services

I am having this issue from past day with Google Play Services & Unity.

What happens is, when I install app directly ot device via Unity, the Google Play Services work fine but when I upload it as beta to play store console and install it via that then it starts to give " DEBUG: Application is pausing, which disconnects the RTMP client" error.

I have a proper SHA1 key.